# Display products from different category on opencart home.twig

Tags: php, twig, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

Can we display only six new products from different category (randomly selected) and display it in home.twig (HOME PAGE) in flexslider. I want to do this manually without designing it in admin dashboard.

[image: Something similar to this]

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do it

**1. Clone Featured Module**

Clone the featured product module, and add products you want to display.

**2. Manually**

You can do it directly from html modules, or in home.twig file.

here is the free module https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=36324